# If $p\neq 0$, then there are $x_+$ and $x_-$ with $x_\pm ^2=p$ , $p\in \mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

If $p\neq 0$, then there are $x_+$ and $x_-$ with $x_\pm ^2=p$ , $p\in \mathbb{C}$.

Hello,

I guess case-by-case analysis with $p\in \mathbb{R}$ and $p\in \mathbb{C}\backslash \mathbb{R}$.

But I don't even know how to start.

Comment: It is very easy to prove if you use polar coordinates. Do you know about them?

Comment: Not yet.. Sorry!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p\neq 0$ be a complex number. Then there exist unique real numbers $a,b$ such that $p=a+i b$ by construction of the complex numbers. Define the function $$\operatorname{sgn}: \Bbb R \to \{-1,0,1\}: x\mapsto \begin{cases}-1&, x<0 \\ 0 &, x=0\\1 &,x=1\end{cases}.$$

Define $C:=a^2+b^2$. Because $C\geq 0$, we can set $\sqrt C$ as the unique positive square root of $C$. Let $\sqrt{C+a}$ be the positive real square root of $C+a$ if the latter is positive, or else let it denote $i$ times the positive real square root of $-C-a$. Analogous for $\sqrt{C-a}$.

Define $$x_\pm=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\sqrt{C+a} + i \cdot \operatorname{sgn}(b)\sqrt{C-a}\right).$$ Then we have (I will leave the calculations to you, reference [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareRoot.html)) $x_\pm^2=p$.

I will also leave it to you to show that $x_-\neq x_+$.

After having shown this you have achieved a proof of your statement.

**Remark.** This result was obtained by solving the equation $(c+ i d)^2=a+i b$ for $c$ and $d$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93843/discussion-on-answer-by-maximilian-janisch-if-p-neq-0-then-there-are-x-an).